# Is this question about an oni with a dragon on them on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

I recently flagged ***[this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/62741/what-is-the-origin-of-oni-with-a-dragon-wrapped-around-them)*** for not being suitable for [Anime and Manga Stack Exchange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/), however, with recent edits, this question does seem on-topic although I cannot really tell if it is.

[image]

This was the original post. Based off the confusing wording, one would think that this was an identification request about an image they saw of an oni with a dragon wrapped around them. Based off the edits made by Aki Tanaka, this was not the intent of the post and was only off-topic due to bad/confusing wording.

[image]

This is the post now. Although still closed, it seems generally on topic for Anime and Manga Stack Exchange, and does seem like it should be re-opened.

So, is the new post (edited) allowed and on-topic on Anime and Manga Stack Exchange? Or should it (and will it) remain closed?

**EDIT!**

This question has been officially deleted by reasons of moderation. It cannot be viewed unless you can see deleted posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rephrasing definitely helps this question to the point I would not consider it a Identification request anymore. However the question seems to pose several different questions, which would make it a fairly broad question which could probably best be split into 2 separate questions.

The questions as posed by the OP in the question:

1. What is the name of this trope:

> I'm trying to get a better grasp on oni symbolism and references, and "oni with a dragon wrapped around their torso" is something I can't find anything about.

2. What is the meaning of a dragon wrapped around the torso / what does a oni with a dragon around it's waist symbolize?

> I'm looking for what it means if an oni has a dragon wrapped around their torso

3. What is the origin of oni with a dragon wrapped  around them

> Question title: What is the origin of oni with a dragon wrapped around them?

Looking at these questions my suggestion would be to combine 1 & 3 into a [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes) question:

- What is the name of this trope, and where does it come from.

[asking for trope origins](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btropes%5D+what+is+the+origin) and [asking for trope names](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btropes%5D+what+name) is generally considered on topic.

And a questions that's more focused on [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes) / [symbolism](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism)

- What does a dragon wrapped around the torso Symbolize

or given that the op is specifically looking for it's symbolism in combinations with demons (oni)

- What does a dragon wrapped around the torso of an oni symbolize?

Which also is generally considered [on topic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolism)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for claryfying that. You're right that the question is *kind of* asking multiple things at once (which I didn't notice, being an idiot) which should be separated into different questions. Still make a good point, +1 & accept.

Comment: I just noticed that [the question garnered 3 upvotes (OP rep 31)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/60538/dragonfish?tab=reputation) but the overall score of question is 0. Why? [cc @ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟ]

Comment: No clue. I don't (completely) understand how this site functions, only being here for about 51 days in UTC. May be a glitch, but I'm assuming 3 people who saw it as off-topic downvoted it. Then after it was edited to what seems on-topic, it gained 3 upvotes.

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟッ is correct. The question currently has 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes. Once you have 1000 rep, you'll gain the privilege of being able to view a question's upvotes/downvotes. More information here: https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user

Comment: @FumikageTokoyami the accounts been deleted. Clicking the link you gave will lead to nowhere :/ not sure when or why but that's that

Comment: @ᴅᴀɴɪᴇʟ Thanks for the update.